# MVC Web Api 2 [FromUri] parameter binding and querystring is different

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having a very weird case in my querystring for [FromUri].
The code below is my model parameter

```
public class PagingParams
{
    public PagingParams()
    {
        // set the default values
        this.PageNo = 1;
        this.PageSize = 30;
    }

    public int PageNo { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public string OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller code.

```
[Route("search")]
[ResponseType(typeof(PagingList<EmailTemplatesInfo>))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Search(SearchParams searchOption, [FromUri] PagingParams p)
{
    // Check
    if (searchOption == null) return BadRequest("Invalid search options");

    // Filter EmailTemplate by Keyword
    var emailTemplate = db.EmailTemplates.Where(et => et.Name.Contains(searchOption.Keyword) ||
                                                      et.Description.Contains(searchOption.Keyword)).ProjectTo<EmailTemplatesInfo>();

    // Filter by Status
    emailTemplate = emailTemplate.Where(et => searchOption.Status.Contains(et.Status));

    // Check & Set
    if (p == null) p = new PagingParams();

    // Set Default Sort
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.OrderBy)) p.OrderBy = DEFAULT_ORDERBY;

    return Ok(new PagingList<EmailTemplatesInfo>(p, emailTemplate));

}
```

Base on the code above if i want to pass in Parameter Binding for PagingParam.

Should be this url

- search?PageNo=1&PageSize=10&OrderBy=CreatedOn

But the result i get in swashbuckle it become

- search?p.PageNo=1&p.PageSize=10&p.OrderBy=CreatedOn

the object name for PagingParam need to append in the querystring

Comment: Can you try to debug your application using the expected query string and see if the parameters were bound correctly inside the controller action? I'm thinking if they were bound correctly, then the issue might be with swashbuckle.

Comment: @OJRaqueño I tried it require me to append the p. to ensure the parameter passed in to the model..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix which. 
Required to write IFilterOperation to overwrite it..
It might not the best way but it solve my problem.

```
public class HandleFromUriParam : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        string[] splitter = null;
        var fromUriParams = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters().
            Where(param => param.GetCustomAttributes<FromUriAttribute>().Any()).ToArray();

        foreach (var param in fromUriParams)
        {
            var fromUriAttribute = param.GetCustomAttributes<FromUriAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            // Check
            if (fromUriAttribute != null)
            {
                var operationParam = operation.parameters;

                foreach (var item in operationParam)
                {
                    if (item.name.Contains(param.ParameterName))
                    {
                        splitter = item.name.Split('.');
                        item.name = splitter[splitter.Length - 1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to fix it:
[FromUri(Name = "")] PagingParams p